# How to merge two data frames

Tags: r, join, merge

So let's say that I have two data frames. So for example:

```
a <- c(10,20,30,40)
b <- c('b', 'p', 't', 'x')
c <- c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE)
d <- c(2.5, 8, 10, 7)
df1 <- data.frame(a,b,c,d)


e<-c(2.5,2.5,8,8,8,10,10,10)
f<-c(T, T, F, F, F, T, F, T)
df2<- data.frame(e,f)
```

I know that all the values of column e in dataframe 2 are contained in column d of dataframe 1.

I want to be able to place column b into dataframe 2 so that it would look like this:

```
e<-c(2.5,2.5,8,8,8,10,10,10)
f<-c(T, T, F, F, F, T, F, T)
b<-b("b", "b", "p", "p", "p", "t", "t", "t")
df2<- data.frame(e,f,c)
```

That is, where a value in column e in dataframe 2 is equal to a value in column d of dataframe 1, I want to place the value of column C corresponding to that value in column D into a new column in Dataframe 2.

In reality, I am using much larger datasets than this, so I am hoping for something that does this in a timely manner(i.e preferably not nested for loops). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Answer (score 2):

We can do a `merge` in `base R`

```
merge(df2, df1[c('b', 'd')], by.x = 'e', by.y = 'd')
```

Comment: nice to see `merge` solution, + 1

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! both solutions work like a charm and are a lot quicker than what I was doing:)

Answer (score 1):

Another base R solution using `match`

```
df2$b <- df1$b[match(df2$e,df1$d)]
```

which gives

```
> df2
     e     f b
1  2.5  TRUE b
2  2.5  TRUE b
3  8.0 FALSE p
4  8.0 FALSE p
5  8.0 FALSE p
6 10.0  TRUE t
7 10.0 FALSE t
8 10.0  TRUE t
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! This worked like a charm.